# Imported from Excel XY coordinates into ArcMap 10.4.1 display at zero latitude

Tags: coordinate-system, arcmap, import, excel

When importing spatial data from excel, the imported point layer is displayed onto 34 latitude and 0 longitude. It should be 47-48 latitude and 37-39 longitude.
What could be causing it?
I tried to change the spatial reference, it does not seem to help.

[image]

Comment: What coordinate system have you tried to display the data in?

Comment: It's GCS_WGS_1984, projected into WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_37N.

Comment: When you did this did you set the data frame to GCS_WGS_1984 then add the data using the XY tool then project on the fly into WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_37N?

Comment: I just set the coordinate system in the settings for the XY tool for the once that I have mentioned above.
The issue was resolved when in imported the point layer to the empty project, exported as as shapefile and then imported into the dataframe that i was working with.
Still did not understand what was the problem((

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check your unit of measure. Currently, your unit is in Decimal Degrees but what you exported are on a LAT/LONG format.

Answer (score 0):

So I do this often at my work, and the most common reasons this occurs for me are the following:

- When importing your long/lat coordinates from excel, be sure they are in decimal degrees and not Degrees/min/seconds
- Right click on your layers tab and go to Data Frame Properties. Be sure that your units are being run through Decimal Degrees. Commonly it's under feet, the coordinates won't be read properly from your table if it's not in this scale.
- Go to your attribute table and see what your field is being read as. For Long/Lat, double seems to work the best. If it's not in double, you can add a new field to your attributes and make sure that the type is listed as double. Then using field calculator, you can make this new field equal your original Long/Lat field.
- When in excel, make sure there are no spaces in any of your column headers. For whatever reason, this will cause an issue when bringing the table into GIS
- Last but not least, make sure they aren't switched. I have before accidentally put longitude values in my latitude field and when importing into GIS, received 0s as a result!